# popover calendar when user presses a button

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, popup, uipopovercontroller

I want to show a popup with a calendar when the user presses a button. I have seen lots of popups but they don't include the arrow from the button pressed. I want something similar to the image below. I have done a calendar and I don't know how to insert it into a popover. Can someone give me a trick?

I know how to make a popover with a tableview but no with an other viewcontroller.

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: This website is for asking questions, not just telling us what you want.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, my question is that I don't know how to put a calendar into a popover, is there somebody that know how to do it? I have the calendar done, what I'm asking for is how to put it into a popover. Sorry if my question seems that I'm asking for people to do my job cause it's not.

Comment: Creating a `UIPopoverController` with another view controller is the same as creating one with a table view. A popover is always created with another view controller. Show what you have tried so far to create the popover with your calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I'm going to explain it step by step:

1- First of all I have created a popover
2- Then I have include a [calendar](https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar) to my project 
3- Then I have add the calendar view into the popover

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender {

UIButton * popoverButton = (UIButton*) sender;

CKCalendarView *calendar = [[CKCalendarView alloc] initWithStartDay:startMonday];
self.calendar = calendar;
calendar.delegate = self;

self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
self.minimumDate = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:@"20/09/2012"];

self.disabledDates = @[
                       [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:@"05/01/2013"],
                       [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:@"06/01/2013"],
                       [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:@"07/01/2013"]
                       ];

calendar.onlyShowCurrentMonth = NO;
calendar.adaptHeightToNumberOfWeeksInMonth = YES;
calendar.tag = 0;

calendar.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 320);

self.dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, CGRectGetMaxY(calendar.frame) + 4, self.view.bounds.size.width, 24)];
[self.view addSubview:self.dateLabel];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(localeDidChange) name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification object:nil];


popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]

                                    init];

UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]

                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 220)];

popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

popoverContent.view = calendar;


//resize the popover view shown
//in the current view to the view's size

popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =

CGSizeMake(300, 220);


//create a popover controller

self.myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]

                          initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];


//present the popover view non-modal with a
//refrence to the button pressed within the current view
//UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
[self.myPopover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverButton.frame

                                        inView:self.view

                      permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp

                                      animated:YES];
```

}

Here's the most important part of the code. If anyone wants help don't doubt to ask it!